# Переключение в Android Studio в XML

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml

Постоянно напрягает что при переключении в xml-файлы, по умолчанию, сначала открывается вкладка Design а не Text. И постоянно приходится переключаться. Можно ли это изменить в настройках?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Настройка "предпочитать XML редактор":

Settings.. -> Editor -> Layout Editor -> Prefer XML editor - отметить галочкой.